# Google Maps Canvas custom markers not drawing properly

Tags: html, google-maps, canvas

I'm new to html5 and am having a problem with drawing custom markers. I tried using the code from [this](http://saikotroid.blogspot.com/2011/12/creating-custom-google-maps-marker-with.html) tutorial. I'm trying to use circles instead of rounded rectangles but my circles are getting cut off on the right side. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrfWm.jpg) is a screenshot. I tried replacing the rectangle drawing code with

```
context.arc(radius,radius,radius,0,2*Math.PI, true);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

never mind I was setting the canvas height and width incorrectly.